# Unable to parse JSON output in jquarymobile's html page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed screens for my android application using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. Using below js and css files in my html page

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, Screens are working fine and I need to bind data from db to my screen for that I have created web services that are giving me JSON outputs. One of the JSON outputs that I'm trying to parse in html is as below.

```
[
 {"rest_id": 35, "rest_name": "Just 10"},
 {"rest_id": 36, "rest_name": "Egg Zone"},
 {"rest_id": 37, "rest_name": "Tandoor & Curries"},
 {"rest_id": 38, "rest_name": "China Bite"}
]
```

Now, to my HTML Page. What I'm trying here is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON("MyURL", function( data ) {
            alert('success');
            /* My Logic for getting value from JSON output */
        });
     </script>
```

Issue here is I'm not even getting alert msg that I'm trying to print on the page.

I'm new to all these .. So if any1 can tell me where and what I'm doing wrong would be great help.

Thanks all

Mayur

Comment: if the ajax request is 200 OK the reason why it won't trigger the alert is either because of the invalid JSON, or because of the `Content-Type` of the response is not properly set as `application/json`

Comment: Actually I have developed Webservice using hibernate mapping and in my dispater-servalet.xml file I have set it as this <entry key="json" value="application/json" />

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn Can u please tell me more about how json can be invalid?? Cause I think that might be the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not familiar with PhoneGap but it seems in your script you have written code to get data. There should be something about request too. As Ajax is about request and response.

```
  $.ajax({
  url : '${resourceURL}',
  data : data,//send Request 
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : "json",
  success : function(data) {
    // something my be alert(success)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided it seems you are not calling that `$.getJSON()` function. You need to call it somehow (from some event listener for example) or you can execute it when DOM is ready by

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("MyURL",
    function(data){
      alert('success');
      /* My Logic for getting value from JSON output */
    }
  );
});
```

just to see if it is working.

Comment: Well, It works well When I pass This URL  http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?
But it isn't working for my url.